# Encountering MalformedInputexception while decoding UTF-8 text in java

Tags: java, utf-8

I am forming a file using UTF-8 encoder as follows by reading text from DB:

```
csvBufWr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fname), Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder()), (int) buffersize);
csvBufWr.write(recordtoinsert);
csvBufWr.newLine();
```

Then based on the records this file is compared with another file (from another System which I have no control upon), using shell script.
After merging, I have to create an excel sheet using Apache POI. So I read the file as below and write to excel sheet.

```
CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
//decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);

csvBufRdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(pathAndFileName), decoder));
// read the file line by line, parse the record and write them
// to the XL file
while ((line = csvBufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!line.isEmpty() && line.length() > 8) {
        parseAndWrite2Sheet(line, sheet, workBook, sheetName);
    }
}
```

However, I encounter MalformedInputException on `line = csvBufRdr.readLine()` after reading some random number of lines. I have checked the file being read thoroughly, and there seems to be no weird character. Even when I delete the line on which exception occurred and 2 lines above and below it, I encounter the exception at the same line number. Adding `decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE)` seems to overcome the issue, but everyone is worried whether we are dropping a record or a character which is unacceptable.

I compared the excel generated and the file used, there seems to be no difference. Can anyone point to me why this is happening?

Is it because of the merging in LINUX, which AFAIK deals by default with UTF files and seems unlikely to be causing the issue.

I am at my wits end!

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a short but complete program *without* using POI? I'd expect to see the issue just on writing and then reading...

Comment: @JonSkeet I am getting the exception much before moving to POI part. That comes into picture only with the call to `parseAndWrite2Sheet()`. I

Comment: Right - so you should be able to write a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem easily, right?

Comment: Yes, but this code is for company I am working for and I can't share the data as it is sensitive to business. You can assume the above code to be complete, just by ignoring the POI reference to my question, assume inside for... loop all i m doing is reading the data and printing to console. The error is in `br.readLine()`, I just tried this scenario, just to be sure.

Comment: I didn't ask for the sensitive code or data. I asked for a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. That shouldn't require anything sensitive - but it does require you to do some diagnostic work first. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vkSpyKgw

I tested with the file throwing the exception. With IGNORE uncommented, this code works fine. As soon as I comment the `IGNORE` line, it throws an exception at line 838 in my file. I deleted line 831-840 and ran the same code and - same exception at same line number?!?

Comment: Now edit it into the question, and provide sample data which reproduces the problem... (It doesn't need to be *useful* data - just enough to reproduce the issue.)